# ¿Cómo mover nombre junto a edad en un vector?

Tags: c++, ordenamiento, array

Tengo dos vectores uno de nombres y otro de edades, el vector de edades se ordena de mayor a menor, ¿cómo puedo hacer que al nombre que le pertenece la edad se mueva de posición junto con el vector de edades? (en funciones)

```
void orden(int vec[]) //f. edades ordenadas
{
    int i=0;
    int j=100;
    int h=0;
    while(i<5)
    {
        j=100;
        for(int x=i;x<5;x++)
        {
            if(vec[x]<j)
            {
                j=vec[x];
                h=x;
            }   
        }
        int aux=vec[i];
        vec[i]=vec[h];
        vec[h]=aux;
        i++;
    }

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        cout<<vec[x]<<endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: donde esta el otro vector? si se ingresan con los mismos indices, lo unico que tienes que hacer es moverlo igual que como mueves este

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parto de la base de que tu código de ordenación es correcto y funciona.

Si asumimos que el registro `i` del primer vector está relacionado con el registro `i` del segundo vector, la ordenación es trivial:

```
void orden(int vec[], std::string vec2[]) //f. edades ordenadas
{
 int i=0;
 int j=100;
 int h=0;
 while(i<5)
 {
    j=100;
    for(int x=i;x<5;x++)
    {
      if(vec[x]<j)
          {
          j=vec[x];
          h=x;
          } 
    }
    // equivalente a tu codigo antiguo. Evitas usar variable temporal
    std::swap(vec[i],vec[h]);   // Ordenacion vec
    std::swap(vec2[i],vec2[h]); // Ordenacion vec2
    i++;
 }

 for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
 {
    cout<<vec[x]<<endl; 
 }
}
```

Ahora, salvo que sea un requisito del ejercicio, plantéate usar `std::vector` en vez de arrays crudos `int vec[]`.